# Splitting paragraph based on special characters and parantheses and brackets in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, paragraph

I am trying to split a small paragraph in to sentences based on full stop commas and parantheses like () {} and []. How to do such thing using Java Regex

For example if I have a Paragraph like

> So far I like this car and it is fun to drive. It works very well as a daily driver and has some good kick, although it is still far from a sports car. I have one major issue with this car.Volvo has built heating elements into the windshield (small wires every few millimeters). At night all lights reflect off of these wires and makes the lights blurry. It is a huge safety issue and is extremely annoying. Due to this issue alone, I am not sure if I will keep this car very long. Although it is nice to have a heated steering wheel, skip the Climate Package if you buy this car.

My result of Splitted paragraph should be

> So far I like this car and it is fun to drive
>
> It works very well as a daily driver and has some good kick
>
> although it is still far from a sports car
>
> I have one major issue with this
>
> Volvo has built heating elements into the windshield
>
> small wires every few millimeters
>
> At night all lights reflect off of these wires and makes the lights blurry
>
> It is a huge safety issue and is extremely annoying
>
> Due to this issue alone
>
> I am not sure if I will keep this car very long
>
> Although it is nice to have a heated steering wheel
>
> skip the Climate Package if you buy this car

Comment: Please explain what part of this simple programming problem is giving you difficulty?  If the answer is "all of it", then I recommend you read http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and / or all of this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: You can't do this using regular expressions, since your grammar is obviously context-free grammar. Imagine a sentence "hello (beautiful (indeed) world)". What's the parse tree for that? Is that ['hello', 'beautiful', 'indeed', 'world'] or ['hello', 'beautiful world', 'indeed']? Or just ['hello', 'beautiful (indeed) world']? Regular expressions does not construct automata that can check how deep in your parse you are, which will not allow you to pair tokens like (), [], etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
String str = "...";
str = str.replaceAll(" ?[,.()]+ ?", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

If you want an array, use this:

```
    String[] strArr = str.split(" ?[,.()]+ ?");
    for(String strr : strArr)
    {
        System.out.println(strr);
    }
```

Yields:

```
So far I like this car and it is fun to drive
It works very well as a daily driver and has some good kick
although it is still far from a sports car
I have one major issue with this car
Volvo has built heating elements into the windshield
small wires every few millimeters
At night all lights reflect off of these wires and makes the lights blurry
It is a huge safety issue and is extremely annoying
Due to this issue alone
I am not sure if I will keep this car very long
Although it is nice to have a heated steering wheel
skip the Climate Package if you buy this car
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
String reg = "\\ ?[.,()\\[\\]{}]+\\ ?";
String[] res = str.split(reg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
 \s*[.,()\[\]{}]+\s*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Sample code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "So far I like this car and it is fun to drive. It works very well as a daily driver and has some good kick, although it is still far from a sports car. I have one major issue with this car.Volvo has built heating elements into the windshield (small wires every few millimeters). At night all lights reflect off of these wires and makes the lights blurry. It is a huge safety issue and is extremely annoying. Due to this issue alone, I am not sure if I will keep this car very long. Although it is nice to have a heated steering wheel, skip the Climate Package if you buy this car.";

        String[] output = str.split("\\s*[.,()\\[\\]{}]+\\s*");

        for (String s : output) {
            System.out.println(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
So far I like this car and it is fun to drive

It works very well as a daily driver and has some good kick

although it is still far from a sports car

I have one major issue with this car

Volvo has built heating elements into the windshield

small wires every few millimeters

At night all lights reflect off of these wires and makes the lights blurry

It is a huge safety issue and is extremely annoying

Due to this issue alone

I am not sure if I will keep this car very long

Although it is nice to have a heated steering wheel

skip the Climate Package if you buy this car
```